# wso2is configure email settings per tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to use self signed up and password recovery from wso2is on a multi-tenant configuration.

Everything is documented here :

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation
  and
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Password+Recovery

But the problem is if I use

> Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true

the mail smtp from setting that as to be configured in axis.xml is not tenant dependant :

```
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
<parameter name="mail.smtp.from">sampleemail@gmail.com</parameter>
[...]
```

And if I put

> Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=false

how can I get the mail template correctly filled to send it by myself ?
It's written is the doc :
`Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true`
`This enables the internal email sending module. If false, the email sending data is available to the application via a Web service. Thus the application can send the email using its own email sender.`

But what is the Web service name or workflow ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed is a global configuration in Identity Server 5.2.0 release. It will be a tenant wise property in next release. (You can try it with latest [code](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/) ).

In self-signup and password recovery flows, we send a confirmation code with the username through an email. If you disable Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed property, it will be returned the  confirmation code from same web service. (UserInfoRecoveryService).

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see any improvement to send email with different stmp configuration per tenant in wso2is-5.3.0...